# hadoop mapreduce job on Cassandra result is wrong

Tags: hadoop, nosql, mapreduce, cassandra

I have 7 node cassandra (1.1.1) and hadoop (1.03) cluster ( tasktracker install same on every cassandra node).

and my column family use wide row pattern.  1 row contains about 200k columns (max about 300k).

My problem is when we use Hadoop to run analytic jobs ( count numbers of occurrence of a word) the result i received is wrong ( result is too lower as I expected in test records)

there 's one strange when we monitoring on job tracker is map progress task indicate wrong ( in my image below ) , And number of "Map input records" when i rerun job ( same data) is not same.

[image]
here is my init job code:

```
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJobName(this.jobname);
    job.setJarByClass(BannerCount.class);

    job.setMapperClass(BannerViewMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(BannerClickReducer.class);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(job.getConfiguration(), "9160");
    ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(job.getConfiguration(), "192.168.23.114,192.168.23.115,192.168.23.116,192.168.23.117,192.168.23.121,192.168.23.122,192.168.23.123");
    ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(job.getConfiguration(), "org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner");
    ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(job.getConfiguration(), KEYSPACE, COLUMN_FAMILY, true);
    ConfigHelper.setRangeBatchSize(job.getConfiguration(), 500);


    SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate();
    SliceRange sliceRange = new SliceRange();
    sliceRange.setStart(ByteBufferUtil.EMPTY_BYTE_BUFFER);
    sliceRange.setFinish(ByteBufferUtil.EMPTY_BYTE_BUFFER);
    sliceRange.setCount(200000);
    predicate.setSlice_range(sliceRange);
    ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(job.getConfiguration(), predicate);

    String outPathString = "BannerViewResultV3" + COLUMN_FAMILY;
    if (fs.exists(new Path(outPathString)))
        fs.delete(new Path(outPathString), true);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outPathString));

    job.setInputFormatClass(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(28);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return 1;
```

Comment: Is there any mention in the logs of a reason why some of the mappers failed and had to be rerun?

Comment: there 's no error message in tasktracker log, and there 's no failed mapper or reducer . But ..! i'm very confuse now!!